Cannot create AWS cloudformation stack with template: Invalid template resource property 'properties'
I am new to aws cdk. I am trying to learn from the cdk-workshop and aws is not letting me create stack with my own template. I am trying to upload this file in AWS directly. here is the code for that:
{
    "Resources": {
        "S3Bucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {
                "BucketName": "My Name",
                "AccessControl": "PublicRead"
            },
            "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
            "UpdateReplacePolicy": "Retain"
        }
    }
}

if I try validating this syntax then I get:
cdk-workshop-typescript %] aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://cdk-stack.json
{
    "Parameters": []
}

and AWS cloudformation playform errors out with Invalid template resource property 'properties'
I do not understand what is wrong with my template

This is plain CloudFormation, not CDK. Are you generating the template with CDK? The error message says that your template contains properties instead of Properties.
